# Angular JavaScript How to download only preview information for audio without downloading audio file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html5-audio

During development of custom audio list viewer I faced with issue that for very long list of audio files, if bunch of files will be downloading at the same time than it could took a quite a long time:

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport #scroller
                             autosize
                             class="content"
                             style="height: 100%">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let groupAudio of groupedAudios; let i = index" class="example-item">
    <div [class.selected]="true"
          class="btn btn-dark custom_obj-audio"
          [ngClass]="{'custom_obj-audio-button-green' : isGroupAudioSelected(i), 'custom_obj-audio-button-red': !isGroupAudioSelected(i)}"
          (click)="onSelectGroupAudio(i)">
      <p *ngFor="let name of getAudioName(i)" style="display: block; margin: 3px; word-wrap:normal; height: fit-content;">
        {{name}}
      </p>
      <div matListItemLine style="height: fit-content; width: 100%;">
        <div *ngFor="let custom_obj of groupAudio.custom_objs">
          <p>{{custom_obj.audioName}}</p>
          <audio controls>
            <source [src]="custom_obj.previewUrl" type="audio/wav">
          </audio>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

As you can see from sample Angular template code, I am using virtual scroll and adding a new audio each time when list is scrolled, this triggers start loading audio file from server ...

I could implement adding `src` to audio tag using `onclick` event, but it will mean that customer will not see preview information for audio such as audio length ...

Is it possible to download preview information for file without downloading the whole file ?

Comment: Why not change the endpoint to send only the information without the actual file?

Comment: @Konrad As you can see from template code I do not use custom audio player and audio downloading is triggered by browser

Comment: @Konrad I thought it could be done using preload attributehttps://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_preload.asp, but it also triggers the whole file downloading of audio

Comment: There's preload="metadata" according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#usage_notes

Comment: Yes, looks like it should be preload="metadata", but i see that browser downloading the whole file anyway ...